# Access a list within an element of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` which has a list of integers inside one of the columns. I'd like to access the individual elements within this list. I've found a way to do it by using `tolist()` and turning it back into a `DataFrame`, but I am wondering if there is a simpler/better way. In this example, I add Column `A` to the middle element of the list in Column `B`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : (1,2,3), 'B': ([0,1,2],[3,4,5,],[6,7,8])})
df['C'] = df['A'] + pd.DataFrame(df['B'].tolist())[1]
df
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A bit more straightforward is:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B'].apply(lambda x:x[1])
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me at the end.

Answer (score 7):

One option is to use the `apply`, which should be faster than creating a data frame out of it:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df.apply(lambda row: row['B'][1], axis = 1)
```

Some speed test:

```
%timeit df['C'] = df['A'] + pd.DataFrame(df['B'].tolist())[1]
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 567 µs per loop
%timeit df['C'] = df['A'] + df.apply(lambda row: row['B'][1], axis = 1) 
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 406 µs per loop
%timeit df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B'].apply(lambda x:x[1])
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 250 µs per loop
```

OK. Slightly better. @breucopter's answer is the fastest.

Answer (score 5):

You can also simply try the following:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B'].str[1]
```

Performance of this method:

```
%timeit df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B'].str[1]
#1000 loops, best of 3: 445 µs per loop
```