# Unable to access list from csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I have below content in my csv file, which I am trying to read last column from csv using pandas. And after successful fetching of last column x2. I am unable to access the column from the output. Instead if I try to index the x2 column, I am getting rows. But I want columns.

**CSV File:**

```
symbol,close,low,high,x0,x1,x2
ACC,-1.41,1241.5,1270.0,-1.41,"[1221241.5, 1270, -1.41]","[1241.5, 1270, -1.41]"
ADANIPORTS,-1.61,336.85,346.85,-1.61,"[336.85, 346.85, -1.61]","[336.85, 346.85, -1.61]"
ADANITRANS,3.45,202.8,211.2,3.45,"[202.8, 211.2, 3.45]","[202.8, 211.2, 3.45]"
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("tickerdb.csv", index_col=0)
print((df.iloc[:, -1]))
```

**Output**

```
symbol
ACC           [1241.5, 1270, -1.41]
ADANIPORTS       [336.85, 346.85, -1.61]
ADANITRANS          [202.8, 211.2, 3.45]
```

I tried accessing the column from the list, but I am getting rows instead.

```
print((df.iloc[:, -1][1]))
```

**New Output:**

```
[336.85, 346.85, -1.61]
```

**But expected output is a column from the list, not row:**

```
1270
346.85
211.2
```

Second solution which I am also fine with would be if somehow I can get

```
#Current output from last column using df.iloc
ACC           [1241.5, 1270, -1.41]
ADANIPORTS       [336.85, 346.85, -1.61]
ADANITRANS          [202.8, 211.2, 3.45]

#If I can get like below for x2 column is also fine for me.
symbol        low     high    change
ACC           1241.5  1270    -1.41
ADANIPORTS    336.85  346.85  -1.61
ADANITRANS    202.8   211.2    3.45
```

Any of above two solutions would be good for me. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are u looking for ``df.high`` or ``df['high']``

Comment: No, I want full column output to be printed from my csv column x2. i.e. I am looking for column of  x2[1]

Comment: Check this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38088525/4985099

Comment: Using @Sushanth tip, this resolves with `df.x2.apply(lambda row: row[1])`

Comment: do you want output as new dataframe for second solution?

Comment: H, I tried but it doesn't give the desired results, instead it is printing like below.
ACC           1
ADANIPORTS    3
ADANITRANS    2

Comment: @komatiraju032 Yes, that would be really helpful, If I can get the new dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call df.head() you will see that you have 6 columns of data, but the last 2 columns (x1 and x2) consist of rows of python lists that have been turned into strings through the use of quotes:

"[336.85, 346.85, -1.61]"

is the value of column x2 on the second row.

From your desired output I think what you want is to get the value at index 1 on each row of column x2 (if that row were a list, not a string that looks like a list).

I think the best thing would be to consider reformating your data, but in the mean time here's hacky workaround for you:

```
df = pd.read_csv("tickerdb.csv", index_col=0)

def get_middle_value(series):
    middle = [row.split(', ')[1] for row in series]
    return middle


print(get_middle_value(df.x2))
```

Comment: Yes it is giving me the list of x[2] correctly. Thanks a lot. It helped.

Comment: No problem Vishal glad I could be of help!

Comment: Just one thing, I would like to know as I am getting list now of x2[1], so to convert list to new dataframe as my desired solution. how can I do it..?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to add that column to the data frame? If so you could write: 

df['middle_value'] = get_middle_value(df.x2)

But if you mean a whole new dataframe you could write:

new_df = pd.DataFrame(get_middle_value(df.x2))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.x2.apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x)).tolist(), columns=['low', 'high', 'change'])
df2.insert(0, column='symbol', value=df.symbol)
```

**Output:**

```
       symbol      low     high  change
0         ACC  1241.50  1270.00   -1.41
1  ADANIPORTS   336.85   346.85   -1.61
2  ADANITRANS   202.80   211.20    3.45
```

Comment: This is a quick solution. Working great.